# thonny plugins need to be restarted?

Tags: python, pyaudio, thonny

[image: Thonny PlugIn Dependency]

I tried to use the pyaudio plugin and after installing it, this showed up.
I have tried shutting down my computer and closing down thonny.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question that receives good answers. Including examples, things you tried, errors in text form etc.